# How to create a previous/next button algorithm?

Tags: javascript

I am building a site with repetitive names for pages like this:

```
 thesame/thesame/1-1.html    
 thesame/thesame/1-2.html
 thesame/thesame/1-3.html
```

first number is the chapter number and the second is page number ,I need to insert a `previous/next` buttons, the next button add 1 to current href and redirect (if you are in page 1-1.html it add 1 so takes you to page 1-2.html and then 1-3.html) and a previous button subtract 1 from the current href.
I tried the following but affects the first number (the chapter numper not page number):

```
 var p = (window.location.href.split('/')[window.location.href.split(‌​'/').length-1].split‌​('.')[0].split('-')[‌​0]*1)+1;
```

this is a demo

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<p>Click the button to locate where in the string a specifed value  occurs.</p>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
<p id="demo"></p>
<script>
function myFunction() {
var str = "http://192.168.1.3:33334/Preview/the-website/3-37.html";
var html = (str.split('/')[str.split('/').length-1].split('-')[0]*1)+1;
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = html;
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please edit your question to be more specific about the problem and improve readability. Include a demonstration of your work so far.

Comment: I also want to say "Hello" and help you out with links for further reading on how to ask :) Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to help keeping Stack Overflows content on the highest possible level and increase your chances getting an appropriate answer.  Nice to have you!

Comment: if i could i would

Comment: if you are satisfied with the answer please close it as well.

Comment: i am just getting .html#

Comment: the last string of the page name has a chapter number and then page number 1-1, 1-2, 1-3, 1-4 maybe this why it's not working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Better to do like this:

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function next(c){
    var maxp = 5; 
    var p = (window.location.href.split('/')[window.location.href.split('/').length-1].split('.')[0].split('-')[1]*1)+1; 
    window.location.href = (p > 0 && p <= maxp) ? c + '-' + p + '.html' : '#';
}
function prev(c){
    var maxp = 5; 
    var p = (window.location.href.split('/')[window.location.href.split('/').length-1].split('.')[0].split('-')[1]*1)-1; 
    window.location.href = (p > 0 && p <= maxp) ? c + '-' +p + '.html' : '#';
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<a onclick="next(1)">next</a>
<a onclick="prev(1)">prev</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Pass the chapter number as argument of next and prev functions

If you do not like to use function call then use it:
for next button:

```
<a onclick="javascript: var maxp = 5; var p = (window.location.href.split('/')[window.location.href.split('/').length-1].split('.')[0]*1)+1; window.location.href = (p > 0 && p <= maxp) ? '1-'+ p + '.html' : '#'">next</a>
```

for previous button:

```
<a onclick="javascript: var maxp = 5; var p = (window.location.href.split('/')[window.location.href.split('/').length-1].split('.')[0]*1)-1; window.location.href = (p > 0 && p <= maxp) ? '1-' + p + '.html' : '#'">prev</a>
```

here maxp is the last page index

Comment: you could try it in the demo in the question and see what you get, still not working

Comment: rutern nothing <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button to see what you have got</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var str = "http://192.168.1.3:33334/Preview/the-website/3-37.html";
    var p = (str.split('/')[str.split.('/').length-1].split('.')[0].split('-')[1]*1)+1;
    
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = p;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>

Comment: i've just had to adjust maxp

Comment: ?? actually i want the navigation to stay in the same chapter ,